# Test Interstitial Ads are not shown in iOS APP

Tags: swift, swift3, ads, admob

Hi I am working on a content based iOS app which uses scrollview.I have tried to add the test banner and interstital admob ads and using CocoaPods,I added banner and interstitial test ads but only the banner test ad is shown and the interstitial ad is not shown at all.Here is the code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UIScrollViewDelegate {

var player:AVAudioPlayer?



@IBOutlet weak var bannerView: GADBannerView!
@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet var pageControl: UIPageControl!

var interstitial: GADInterstitial!

@IBOutlet var musicButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var wallButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var shareButton: UIButton!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
    bannerView.rootViewController = self
    bannerView.load(GADRequest())






    self.scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width,  height: self.view.frame.height)
    let scrollViewWidth : CGFloat = self.scrollView.frame.width
    let scrollViewHeight :CGFloat = self.scrollView.frame.height

    let imgOne = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0,width:scrollViewWidth, height:scrollViewHeight))
    imgOne.image = UIImage(named: "b1")

     createAndLoadInterstitial()


    let imgTwo = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:scrollViewWidth, y:0,width:scrollViewWidth, height:scrollViewHeight))
    imgTwo.image = UIImage(named: "b2")

    let imgThree = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:scrollViewWidth*2, y:0,width:scrollViewWidth, height:scrollViewHeight))//*2 means the position of the scrollview
    imgThree.image = UIImage(named: "b3")



    let imgFour = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:scrollViewWidth*3, y:0,width:scrollViewWidth, height:scrollViewHeight))
    imgFour.image = UIImage(named: "b4")


    self.scrollView.addSubview(imgOne)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(imgTwo)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(imgThree)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(imgFour)
```

fileprivate func createAndLoadInterstitial(){

```
    interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID:"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
    let request = GADRequest()
    request.testDevices = [ kGADSimulatorID ]
    interstitial.load(request)



}

func alertView(_alertView: UIScrollView,willDismissWithButtonIndex buttonIndex:Int){

    if interstitial.isReady{

    interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)

    } else {
    print("Ad wasn't ready")

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your Ad Unit ID, It may be the Admob account related issue and try setting the eCPM value high in the Admob account settings.